# Example data set for the k-Nearest Neighbors algorithm?

Tags: computational-geometry, nearest-neighbor

What is an example of a data set one would use with the `k-Nearest Neighbors` algorithm?

I understand the concept but I am unsure about what kind of data one would use for the x, y coordinates.

Can one provide an example of a dataset (with `x, y` coordinates) for the `nearest-neighbor-k algorithm`?

Comment: Are you going to say something about the answers user1530249?

Answer (score 4):

`NN` search is in a simple way this:

1. You have a database of elements (here you have 2 dimensional points, with
   coordinates `x` and `y`).
2. A `query` comes, which is the same type of the elements of the
   database, thus a 2D point in your case.
3. The goal is to find which is the most identical point of the `query`
   point inside the database.

There are many algorithms which allow us not to search the whole database, but to search only what is interest for the `query`, thus answering the `query`, efficiently.

Example:

Database has 6 2D points: (thus is the `datatset` you are refering to)

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
```

A `query` 2D point comes:

`q = (9, 9)`

The answer is the closest point to `q`, which in this example is the `(5, 5)`.

In a `kNN` search, the `query` asks for the `k` most identical elements of the database, which in our example is the `k` closest points of the database presented above to the query point `q`.

So, for `k = 3`, for example the answer should be:

```
5 5 // the 1st closest point to q
4 4 // the 2nd closest point to q
3 3 // the 3rd closest point to q
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not understand the concept.

`k-NN` isn't limited to datasets with only 2 dimensional points (with `x` & `y` coordinates).

Any dataset could be used with `k-NN`, regardless of the number of features - and you could use many `different distance metrics` (even ones that are not technically valid metrics).